# How to mock Eclipse RCP/CDT CoreModel?

Tags: java, mocking, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, easymock

I'm writing regression tests for a piece of code, which creates an instance of `org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel` class.

In my test I'm trying to mock that class:

```
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;

[...]

final CoreModel coreModel = createMock(CoreModel.class);
```

When I run the test, I get following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2ff679d7
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:619)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setThreadCallbacks(Enhancer.java:612)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerCallbacks(Enhancer.java:581)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:251)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:114)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:88)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:79)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.createMock(EasyMock.java:136)
```

How can I mock a class, which is part of Eclipse RCP/CDT?

Comment: I found [this git repository](https://www.gitorious.org/eclipse-cdt/cdt-core/source/bf33a7e54d5209d974bd4a000ff4b8ca1fe7d8f2:model/org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/CoreModel.java) which contains the CoreModel class that I think you're working with. Is that right?

Comment: @DanTemple The package and class look right, but the source code is different. You can find mine here - https://clck.ru/9KRMA . I imported it into Eclipse by going to the *Plugins* view, right-clicking the project and selectin *Import as source* in the context menu.